# Find all lines containing only the same character and replace with the same amount of another character

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

My goal is to convert a NEWS format (the output of `appstream-util appdata-to-news`) to a markdown format (to use on GitHub/GitLab).

A good approximation for me would be to just go from this:

```
Version 0.5.1
~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Released: 2019-01-03

 * This is a test with a ~ tilde ~~~~
 * Second line
```

to this

```
Version 0.5.1
=============
Released: 2019-01-03

 * This is a test with a ~ tilde ~~~~
 * Second line
```

But my current solution with `tr '~' '='` gives me this:

```
Version 0.5.1
=============
Released: 2019-01-03

 * This is a test with a = tilde ====
 * Second line
```

The regex to find all the lines containing only `~` should be this: `^~*$`
But how can, with bash/sed/awk, replace with the same amount of `=`?

Comment: Is it _only_ tilde-only lines you want to replace, or are there other characters?

Comment: As far as I know is tilde only, beside the new line at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pattern match for lines that contain only tilde characters, and then perform a character-by-character replacement

```
sed '/^~*$/s/~/=/g'
```

Comment: or `sed '/[^~]/!y/~/=/'` if you want to use `sed`'s builtin `tr`

Comment: @don_crissti trying to get my head around "find lines without a tilde; and then don't replace it" :-) Elegant. But not immediately readable...

Comment: Or, `sed -E '/^(.)\1*$/ s/./=/g'` which does not hardcode the tilde character.

Comment: It's more like "on lines with other chars (those lines may or may not contain tilde chars) don't translate...". As to the readability, yes, it's `sed`: it's not for everyone :)

Answer (score 0):

I Tried with below sed command and it worked fine

```
Command: sed '/Version/{n;s/~/=/g}' filename
```

e

```
n_linux_example ~]# sed '/Version/{n;s/~/=/g}' filename
Version 0.5.1
=============
Released: 2019-01-03

 * This is a test with a ~ tilde ~~~~
 * Second line
[root@praveen_linux_example ~]#
```